# Lua AES Encrypting with \xhh encoding

Tags: python, encryption, encoding, lua, aes

in python I implementing AES Encrypting
that encrypt string or binary string with AES-128 and encode the output to regular hex literals like \xhh I want to implementing this function with lua

```
class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.bs = 16
        self.key = key

    def encrypt(self, raw, use_base64=True):
        if Crypto:
            raw = self._pad(raw)
            cipher = AES.new(self.key, mode=AES.MODE_ECB)
            crypted_text = cipher.encrypt(raw)
        else:
            _ = self._pad(raw)
            cipher = pyaes.blockfeeder.Encrypter(
                pyaes.AESModeOfOperationECB(self.key))  # no IV, auto pads to 16
            crypted_text = cipher.feed(raw)
            crypted_text += cipher.feed()  # flush final block

        if use_base64:
            return base64.b64encode(crypted_text)
        else:
            return crypted_text

    def decrypt(self, enc, use_base64=True):
        if use_base64:
            enc = base64.b64decode(enc)

        if Crypto:
            cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB)
            raw = cipher.decrypt(enc)
            return self._unpad(raw).decode('utf-8')

        else:
            cipher = pyaes.blockfeeder.Decrypter(
                pyaes.AESModeOfOperationECB(self.key))  # no IV, auto pads to 16
            plain_text = cipher.feed(enc)
            plain_text += cipher.feed()  # flush final block
            return plain_text

    def _pad(self, s):
        padnum = self.bs - len(s) % self.bs
        return s + padnum * chr(padnum).encode()

    @staticmethod
    def _unpad(s):
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]
```

```
localkey = "30a91c993c721aa9"
localkey = localkey.encode('latin1')
print(localkey)
test_cipher = AESCipher(localkey)
payload = b'{"gwId":"315716865002915c2717","devId":"315716865002915c2717","uid":"315716865002915c2717","t":"1633628358"}'
#payload = payload.encode("utf-8")
encrypted = test_cipher.encrypt(payload,False)
print(encrypted)
```

The Output is:

b'30a91c993c721aa9'
b'\xe15\xf8\xc3\xc1)eW\x19\x0b/\x8d\xaf\xa8\xe0\xb6\xd4\xb7\xf7\xcf\xe4\x02\xa4\xab\xfft\x00]B\xea\xf5\r\xcbI\xef\xf9\xd8\xd6v\x02\xa6&\x0e\xe7\x19\x14\xde\xa3\xd0\xc4\xfb\xcb\xfa\x8c\xb8\x9fd\xa6v@\xdf\x03\xc7\xb8\xe5fe\xaf_\xdc\x931\xff\xfc\xfc\x85\x0b3\x92w\xe7k\x1c~}\xb2"\xe9\xc1\xe0\x9a\x12\xb3\xcak\x8en<t\xdd\x12n9Q\x8eX!\xaba2\x16\x9c'

How can i implemneting this encrypting function in lua with this encoding
i tried some ways and many libraries but the output encoding is not like above
what can i do?

Comment: Which Lua AES library have you tried?

Comment: any kind of different aes library one of them was lua-resty-aes

Comment: my problem is with encoding not encrypting,

Comment: So, your question is about how to convert a binary string to hexadecimal form?

Comment: exactly, How to work with binary strings in lua? and How Convert them to hexadecimal form like /xhh?

Comment: Look at [these 2 functions](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/pure_lua_SHA/blob/9d8317da28436e2d645c0ac2106c8a3a55378f5f/sha2.lua#L4708-L4722)

Comment: i use these functions to convert base64 to bin, but the  answer format is:ß5°├┴)eW↓
╦I∩∙╪╓v☻ª&τ↓¶▐ú╨─√╦·î╕ƒdªv@▀♥╟╕σfe»_▄ô1 ⁿⁿà
3Æwτk∟~}▓"Θ┴αÜ↕│╩kÄn<t▌↕n9QÄX!½a2▬£

Comment: what is \xhh format and how can convert binary, hex or base64 to it??

Comment: You don't need to convert base64 to bin.  You need a binary string for AES. `\xhh` format is just a textual form of binary string (for example, it is useful to insert binary string literal in Python program).

Comment: ok, how generate binary string in lua?

Comment: i get it, all i want is AES Encrypting that represent the output as byte string (\xhh format). or can convert binary data to byte string in Lua Language.so how we can do this?

Comment: \xhh is not needed for AES.  It is only for human.

Comment: I want to communicate with device over the network but only this format accepted, device would not response to any other format, I am very confused.

Comment: Your device knows nothing about this format.  The device expects binary string.  The format is just a way Python programmers write binary strings in their programs.  When migrating to Lua you should forget this format ever existed.

Comment: for example when i send this string to device setpoint of device will change to 30 degree: \x00\x00U\xaa\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00w3.3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe6\xddk\xf4\x1a\x97\xb8\x99\x80\xb2\xbc.\x83\x8b\xd1\xbbtk\x83\x13\x9bL\x1e|s\xbd\xed\xcc\x18\xa0\x1e\xc2N&p:`\xcc\x19\xd2\x97P\xc2 \x84G\r\xa8\x89\xe6su\xaf\xcd\x9b\x12YWH\xf6\xb6\xce-{m\xa7Q/W'\xaf\xab\xea\xef&\xfb\x7f\x9a\xe3-n7\xc4\xf3U\xc7e[e\x18\xd9!\xaao\x0cB\xce\xf5\xf9\xed\x00\x00\xaaU

Comment: binary strings in python represent as b'', how work with binary strings in Lua

Comment: `when i send this string to device` - No.  You send this to Python, and Python sends something else (binary string) to the device.

Comment: In Lua all strings are binary.